# singleton pattern and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, singleton, unique-ptr

`std::unique_ptr` uniquely controls the object it points to and, hence, does not utilize reference counting.  A singleton ensures only one object may be created utilizing reference counting.

Would then `std::unique_ptr` perform identically to a singleton?

Comment: I don't understand how you reached that conclusion!

Comment: Well, there can be an arbitrary number of instances of an `std::unique_ptr<T>`...

Comment: @sftrabbit I confused the principle of `singleton` with that of  `std::unique_ptr` in some mangled way.  Thank you all for providing clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A singleton ensures **only one instance** of a type.

A `unique_ptr` ensures **only one smart pointer** to any instance.

Comment: Your second statement is not necessarily true.

Comment: @PreetKukreti I agree with your answer.  I could be my own worst enemy and assert that my first statement isn't necessarily true either.  You could leverage buggy code to duplicate either.  Consider my use of "ensures" to mean "takes measures to help ensure".  *Perhaps I should edit...*

Comment: no worries, I voted you up anyway, you describe the general idea quite succinctly :)

Answer (score 6):

> Would then std::unique_ptr perform identically to a singleton?

No.  Let's say we have class Foo that's intended to be a singleton.  Using a typical singleton pattern, there's no way to construct more than one Foo.

Having a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` means there will be one pointer to a particular instance of Foo, but that doesn't prevent the creation of other instances of Foo (either with other `unique_ptr`s or with raw pointers to local variables).  Thus Foo, wouldn't be a singleton.

Comment: Nice illustration, but I think you meant `unique_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 4):

`std::unique_ptr` achieves single ownership semantics by only providing a move constructor and no copy constructor or assignment operator.

It is not a case of singleton at all, since you can have multiple `unique_ptrs` referencing different instances of the same type. A singleton doesn't let you construct the type directly, but provides an accessor that manages a sole instance.

Also, Drew's assertion that

> "A unique_ptr ensures only one smart pointer to any instance."

is false. If you simply do:

```
T* nt = new T;
std::unique_ptr<T> up1(nt);
std::unique_ptr<T> up2(nt);
```

then you have two unique pointers owning the same resource - and you will only notice a problem at run time, not compile time. Of course, this is incorrect usage of `unique_ptr`, but this reinforces that a `unique_ptr` does not ensure you anything, it is simply a pointer container that holds sole ownership from its own perspective, and through its api, makes it hard to accidentally create temporary copies.

Furthermore, you can have other (smart) pointer types pointing to the same raw pointer/resource independently of any `unique_ptr`. It is completely up to the using code to define ownership and lifetime policies of its resources and smart pointer instances

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I remember a singelton is a class which can only have one instance. That's completely different. So no.