# C++ unique pointer

Tags: c++

```
class Person
{
public:
    string s;
    ~Person(){ cout << "Destructor" << endl; }
};
void _Person(Person a){ cout << a.s << endl; }
auto main() ->int
{
    unique_ptr<Person> p{new Person()};
    _Person(*p); 
    cout << "New Line" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Destructor
New Line
Destructor
```

why printed "Destructor" two times?

Comment: Because there are two `Person` objects created in your code.

Comment: The argument of the (horribly named) `_Person()` function is passed by value, hence it's copied.

Comment: Your `_Person` function creates a copy, so you have 2 `Person`s. By the way, `_Person` is a reserved name. It's typically best to just avoid `_` prefixes in general since the rules are a bit hard to remember.

Comment: The rules are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) by the way.

Comment: @chris, I augmented my answer with your comment. Is that OK?

Comment: @G.Samaras, Of course.

Comment: Ugh, this `auto main() ->int` is like a plague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you create two `Person` objects in your code.

Take a look at this explanation at your code:

```
class Person // declare a class Person
{
public:
    string s;
    ~Person(){ cout << "Destructor" << endl; }
};

// function that takes a class Person as argument
void _Person(Person a) {
  cout << a.s << endl;
}


auto main() ->int
{
    unique_ptr<Person> p{new Person()}; // creation of one instance
    _Person(*p);                        // creation of second instance,
    // because p is passed by value, which means that the default copy constructor of the
    // class Person is activated, thus another object is created!!

    // when the function you called terminates, the copy goes out of scope,
    //thus ~Person() is called
    cout << "New Line" << endl;
    return 0;
}
// the object you created by new, now goes out of scope and gets deleted,
//thus ~Person() is called
```

But `unique_ptr` allows us to create another object?

Of course. Check out the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/).

These pointers are *unique* for deleting the object.

[EDIT]

Take this into account:

A **singleton** ensures **only one instance** of a type.

A `unique_ptr` ensures **only one smart pointer** to any instance.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906509/singleton-pattern-and-stdunique-ptr)

[EDIT.2]

Nice [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) from chris, which talks about the rules for using an underscore.

To be laconic, I would suggest to change this:

`_Person()`

to this

`Person()`

It's not a compilation mistake, it's just not common.

[EDIT.3]

Generally in C++, you can pass class objects as **references**, in order to avoid copying. Copying can take some time when the objects are instances of *big* classes.

So, I suggest that you change your function:

```
void Person(Person a) {
  cout << a.s << endl;
}
```

to this

```
void Person(Person& a) {
  cout << a.s << endl;
}
```

and run again your code. Can you guess what the output should be now? We pass the instance by reference, thus no copy constructor of `Person` is called.

Answer (score 2):

It is because your function

```
void _Person(Person a){ cout << a.s << endl; }
```

takes argument by value so a copy of the object is created.

```
auto main() ->int
{
    unique_ptr<Person> p{new Person()};
    _Person(*p);                // this calls a function _Person 
                                // with a copy of what p points to
                                // this copy dies at the end of function scope
    cout << "New Line" << endl; // its dctor has been just called
   return 0;
}                               // and now is called dctor for original variable
```

Comment: Here it might be appropriate to mention the differences of `std::unique:ptr` and a singleton.

Comment: Done @πάνταῥεῖ, καλή παρατήρηση (good point). I know you are not Greek. :P It's nice to see that the private_data_public_channel followed my example on editing his answer to explain the behaviour. :)

Comment: @G.Samaras I am glad that you are happy but I haven't followed your example

Comment: Still, happy for a nice explanation. +1

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you and again kind ask for giving a reply [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23767278/1141471) in comments

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 I mentioned my point there. It was/is not appropriate to mention the singleton pattern as a possible solution for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767241/c-static-const-class-members-initialization).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There is provided correct solution there. Moreover there is also showed how singleton can be used (but it is mentioned as possible but not preferred solution, because it has many pitfalls). You can consider undownvoting please

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 If any of the GoF patterns are in question there it's more about the [**Flyweight**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) IMHO. Having certain `static const T` instances along with a certain class to give useful _common_ values like e.g. `ZERO`, `PI`or `NORMAL_MATRIX`, whatever, is a commonly used and valid technique. I hope you get my point now. I will of course leave the same comment on your answer over there.